# Rearrange JSON structure to a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, dataframe, structure

I have the json structure listed below in the form I download.  I would like to put it in a dataframe structure like this rotated form.

Date        Account                 Amount

2019-12-31  capitalSurplus          22165000000

2019-12-31  totalLiab               225307000000

2019-12-31  totalStockholderEquity  33185000000

2019-12-31  minorityInterest        45000000

2019-12-31  otherCurrentLiab        21454000000

2019-12-31  totalAssets             258537000000

2019-12-31  commonStock             41000000
.
.
.
2018-12-31  intangibleAssets        178000000

```
        capitalSurplus          22006000000

        totalLiab               220474000000

        totalStockholderEquity  35932000000
```

{'balanceSheetHistory': {'F': [{'2019-12-31': {'capitalSurplus': 22165000000,
'totalLiab': 225307000000,
'totalStockholderEquity': 33185000000,
'minorityInterest': 45000000,
'otherCurrentLiab': 21454000000,
'totalAssets': 258537000000,
'commonStock': 41000000,
'otherCurrentAssets': 2699000000,
'retainedEarnings': 20320000000,
'otherLiab': 23723000000,
'treasuryStock': -9341000000,
'otherAssets': 20599000000,
'cash': 8437000000,
'totalCurrentLiabilities': 98132000000,
'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': 11863000000,
'shortLongTermDebt': 1168000000,
'otherStockholderEquity': -7728000000,
'propertyPlantEquipment': 37869000000,
'totalCurrentAssets': 114047000000,
'longTermInvestments': 2396000000,
'netTangibleAssets': 33185000000,
'shortTermInvestments': 13851000000,
'netReceivables': 3618000000,
'longTermDebt': 13618000000,
'inventory': 10786000000,
'accountsPayable': 19681000000}},
{'2018-12-31': {'intangibleAssets': 178000000,
'capitalSurplus': 22006000000,
'totalLiab': 220474000000,
'totalStockholderEquity': 35932000000,
'minorityInterest': 134000000,
'deferredLongTermLiab': 247000000,
'otherCurrentLiab': 17270000000,
'totalAssets': 256540000000,
'commonStock': 41000000,
'otherCurrentAssets': 3930000000,
'retainedEarnings': 22668000000,
'otherLiab': 24185000000,
'goodWill': 264000000,
'treasuryStock': -8783000000,
'otherAssets': 17245000000,
'cash': 7111000000,
'totalCurrentLiabilities': 95569000000,
'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': 10412000000,
'shortLongTermDebt': 1700000000,
'otherStockholderEquity': -7366000000,
'propertyPlantEquipment': 37883000000,
'totalCurrentAssets': 114649000000,
'longTermInvestments': 2959000000,
'netTangibleAssets': 35490000000,
'shortTermInvestments': 15925000000,
'netReceivables': 11195000000,
'longTermDebt': 11833000000,
'inventory': 11220000000,
'accountsPayable': 21520000000}},
{'2017-12-31': {'intangibleAssets': 213000000,
'capitalSurplus': 21843000000,
'totalLiab': 222792000000,
'totalStockholderEquity': 35578000000,
'minorityInterest': 126000000,
'deferredLongTermLiab': 232000000,
'otherCurrentLiab': 16402000000,
'totalAssets': 258496000000,
'commonStock': 41000000,
'otherCurrentAssets': 3649000000,
'retainedEarnings': 21906000000,
'otherLiab': 25526000000,
'goodWill': 75000000,
'treasuryStock': -8212000000,
'otherAssets': 18091000000,
'cash': 8934000000,
'totalCurrentLiabilities': 94600000000,
'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': 10762000000,
'shortLongTermDebt': 1960000000,
'otherStockholderEquity': -6959000000,
'propertyPlantEquipment': 36901000000,
'totalCurrentAssets': 116801000000,
'longTermInvestments': 3448000000,
'netTangibleAssets': 35290000000,
'shortTermInvestments': 17554000000,
'netReceivables': 10599000000,
'longTermDebt': 13174000000,
'inventory': 11176000000,
'accountsPayable': 23282000000}},
{'2016-12-31': {'intangibleAssets': 198000000,
'capitalSurplus': 21630000000,
'totalLiab': 208668000000,
'totalStockholderEquity': 29170000000,
'minorityInterest': 113000000,
'otherCurrentLiab': 16277000000,
'totalAssets': 237951000000,
'commonStock': 41000000,
'otherCurrentAssets': 3145000000,
'retainedEarnings': 15634000000,
'otherLiab': 25086000000,
'goodWill': 50000000,
'treasuryStock': -8135000000,
'otherAssets': 14894000000,
'cash': 7828000000,
'totalCurrentLiabilities': 90281000000,
'deferredLongTermAssetCharges': 9705000000,
'shortLongTermDebt': 1361000000,
'otherStockholderEquity': -7013000000,
'propertyPlantEquipment': 33692000000,
'totalCurrentAssets': 108461000000,
'longTermInvestments': 3523000000,
'netTangibleAssets': 28922000000,
'shortTermInvestments': 19642000000,
'netReceivables': 11102000000,
'longTermDebt': 13222000000,
'inventory': 8898000000,
'accountsPayable': 21296000000}}]}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
cols = ['date','text','valeus']
dat = pd.DataFrame(columns = cols)

dt=#idid copy past the json file 

dic=dt['balanceSheetHistory']['F']

for index in range(len(dic)):
  for k in list(dic[index].keys()):
    for k2 in list(dic[index][k].keys()):
      k3=dic[index][k][k2]
      #dflist.append([k,k2,dic[index][k][k2]])
      dat = dat.append({'date':k, 'text':k2,'valeus':k3},ignore_index=True)
```